# How to get entities that a collection property has any of the elments of a list?

Tags: entity-framework, join, iqueryable, related-content

I have this entities:

```
MyEntityA
{
    long IDEntityA;
    List<EntityB> lstEntityB;
    .... (other properties);
}

MyEntityB
{
    long IDEntityB;
    string Name;
    .... (other properties)
}


List<long> lstIDsEntitiesB; //this list has many IDs of entities B.
```

I would like to get all the entities A which property lstEntitiesB has one or more entities which ID is on lstIDsEntitiesB.

I don't know if I have to use a join or there are any other way, perhaps with any or contains.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class MyEntityA
    {
        public long IDEntityA;
        public List<MyEntityB> lstEntityB;
    }

    class MyEntityB
    {
        public long IDEntityB;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class Test
    {
        List<long> lstIDsEntitiesB; 

        public void TestAlvaroProblem()
        {
            List<MyEntityA> entitiesA = new List<MyEntityA>();
            IEnumerable<MyEntityA> filteredOut = entitiesA.Where(a => a.lstEntityB
                            .Select(b => b.IDEntityB).Intersect(lstIDsEntitiesB).Any());
        }        
    }
```

You should select entitiesA where lstEntityB's Ids intersect with lstIDsEntitiesB